# Problem with asp net core 2.2.202 in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I create Asp Net Core 2.2.202 application in Visual Studi 2017.
Project create, but has errors nuget packages
And in properties project missing net core 2.2.
Net Core 2.2.202 installed on this computer.
What could be the problem?
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [ask] for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my broblem by install net core 2.2.105